# Excel vba multiple userform close down unexpectedly

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I got one main userform in excel vba. This main form got 2 buttons to call out 2 different userform.

The first form contains listview, textbox and command button.
The second form contains treeview,textbox and command button.
(all forms including the main form has a command button cancel property set to true so the form will unload when user press escape key)

My goal is to have my main form to show as vbmodeless,
while the other 2 form is set to be vbmodal.

Scenario with first form : Pressing escape key or close the form with close down button of the userform unloads the first form and focus back to main form.

Scenario with second form : Pressing escape key or close the form with close down button of the userform unloads the second form and main form.

The second form works as intended after I change the show modal property to true but that's not what I wanted. Any idea why it behave as so?

Comment: Probably something to do with the code behind the form.